# QFileSystemModel::canFetchMore() returns false always

Tags: qt, qt4

I have the following code in which i want to check if there are any sub directories exist. I expect the canFetchMore() fn to return true(since root directory contains sub directories). But it returns false. Is there any other fn to be called before calling canFetchMore() fn.

```
QFileSystemModel model;
model.setFilter(QDir::AllDirs);
model.setRootPath("/");
QModelIndex index = model.index(model.rootPath());
qDebug()<<index.child(0,0).isValid()<<model.canFetchMore(index)<<index;
```

I have tried using hasChildren() fn and it returns always true irrespective of the folder contains sub-dirs or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, there is no documentation for this. 
The method

```
  model.setRootPath("/");
```

automatically call `model.fetchMore(index);`. Which means at this point all sub-directories are already found. That's why your call `model.canFetchMore(index)` return false, because there is no more sub-directories to fetch.

One way to do it (using [QDir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html), [QFileInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#isDir)):

```
QDir mytopdir("/path/to/dir");
if(mytopdir.exists()){
    QFileInfoList list = mytopdir.entryInfoList();
    foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, list){
        if(fileInfo.isDir()){
            //FOUND IT!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to find if a directory has sub-directories or not

Comment: ". and .." will be considered as directories by QDir. To stop it we should call QDir::setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot); which works on empty directories as well.